# Changing the values in a column with a value from the same column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Is it possible in access to select a record from a given column, and update that same column with the record you selected?

For example:

```
----column----
    test




---------------
```

becomes

```
-----Column------
      test
      test
      test
      test
-------------------
```

Notice the blanks in the first table, and how in the second table those blanks were filled with the value that was in the first row. Is there a way to do this without having to specifically say "update to test"? I'm at a loss as to how to do this without telling Access that it needs to specifically update the blanks to "test".

Comment: The way to update records in Access and other databases is to use `update`.  I have no idea what you are really asking, if you want to update, without `update`.

Comment: I still want to use update, I just dont want to specifically say what it has to update to. I was a way for it to check whatever the first record is in the column, and update the rest of the column to whatever that record is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
    UPDATE Table1, (SELECT TOP 1 Field1 As F FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 Is Not Null)
    SET Field1 = F
    WHERE Field1 Is Null
```

It handles several special cases safely:

- If more than one row has a value in Fleld1, the value from the first such row is used.
- The first row of the table need not have a value in Field1.
- If none of the rows have a value in Field1, nothing bad will happen.

Before:

```
    Field1  Field2  
            apple 
    pet     cat    
            dog    
    color   red    
            blue
```

After:

```
    Field1  Field2  
    pet     apple 
    pet     cat    
    pet     dog    
    color   red    
    pet     blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

- a table MY_TABLE
- a column COL_1
- multiple records of which only one holds a value (not null) for COL_1

The update statement to fill COL_1 of all records with the non-null value :

```
update MY_TABLE
   set COL_1 = (select COL_1 FROM MY_TABLE where COL_1 is not null)
 where COL_1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: I was getting a syntax error on the column name (original column has spaces in the name...yes I know that's bad practice), so I put `[]` around the column name, and it's now telling me `operation must use an updateable query`.

Comment: fixed the column name to contain no spaces, but having the same issue. I don't understand whats wrong. It's not a read only file, nor does it have any relationships.

Comment: confession: I don't have an Access db available right now. I was just answering in a standard SQL way. Maybe it is related to the inner select. The database cannot be sure the query will always return only one value. Other suggestion (not tested): replace inner select by `(select max(COL_1) from MY_TABLE WHERE COL_1 IS NOT NULL)` This will always return only one value. Hope it works.